# Declaring static methods inside of classes declared by functions

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Using the function-class method instead of the actual class object, how do I accomplish declaring static methods inside of a class object and access it by that name.

The ultimate goal being single declaration of both things.

Please ignore non standard notation and implicit variables. Code does run as it is inside of a browser console, so it is valid, if not standard. Look at it more like pseudocode.

Section 1: So that this pattern holds

```
 Be able to use a declared variable name ('Array') as a constructor ('new Array()')

 Be able to use static methods available to same declared variable name ('Array') accessed as an object ('Array.isArray()').
```

Section 2: Do This

Header:  The Obvious Solution

```
 declare some class name function ('foo')

 As part of created js-object when declaring functions, declare property-method accessing same declared class function name ('foo.isFoo')

 declare instance of class ('foo')
```

Section 3: Like This

Header:  The Goal and Ideal

```
  declare some class name function ('foo') with intended static method ('isFoo') to be accessed from main class name ('foo.isFoo')

  declare instance of class ('foo')

  try: what throws an error because ('foo.isFoo') isn't a function but ('c.isFoo') is. How do we declare this as a static function?

  catch: just garbage to throw at the end console feed for clarity
```

instructions

```
a = "animal";

/*  So that this pattern holds  */
console.log("\nSo that this pattern holds")
b =  new Array(a);
console.log("new Array(a) = [" + b + "]");
console.log("Array.isArray(b) = " + Array.isArray(b));

/*  DO THIS  */
console.log("\nDO THIS");
foo = function (f) {
  this.f = f; 
}
foo.isFoo = c => c instanceof foo;
c = new foo(a);
console.log("new foo(a) = " + c);
console.log("foo.isFoo(c) = " + foo.isFoo(c));

/*  LIKE THIS  */
console.log("\nLIKE THIS");
foo = function (f) {
  this.f = f; 
  this.isFoo = c => c instanceof foo;
}
c = new foo(a);
console.log("new foo(a) = " + c);
try {console.log("foo.isFoo(c) = " + foo.isFoo(c));}
catch {console.log("foo.isFoo is not a function\n     foo.isFoo(c) should = true");}
```

console output

```
So that this pattern holds                          debugger eval code:4:9
new Array(a) = [animal]                             debugger eval code:6:9
Array.isArray(b) = true                             debugger eval code:7:9

DO THIS                                             debugger eval code:10:9
new foo(a) = [object Object]                        debugger eval code:16:9
foo.isFoo(c) = true                                 debugger eval code:17:9

LIKE THIS                                           debugger eval code:20:9
new foo(a) = [object Object]                        debugger eval code:26:9
foo.isFoo is not a function
     foo.isFoo(c) should = true
```

This is meant to be identical in behavior as this

```
class Point {
    constructor( ...args ) {
        ...do stuff...
    }
    static isPoint( c ) { return c instanceof this; }
}
point = new Point( 3, 7 );
console.log( Point.isPoint( point ) );
console.log( Point.isPoint( Object ) );
```

Comment: There's so much going on here...implicit global variables, violation of naming expectations (constructors should follow PascalCase), use of the Array constructor instead of a data literal (`new Array(x)` doesn't do what you think it does if x is not a number), why `try/catch`, what error are you expecting here? I can't even follow this enough to understand what the question is? Please strip this down to a minimal verifiable complete example.

Comment: Hi, Question needs to be more clearer with appropriate snippet, please edit the question

Comment: Edited question per request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, post-edit I understand your question.

### TL;DR **No**, there is no *good* way to do what you want.

In a constructor function `this` is bound by the `new` operator to be the newly-created instance, there's no dynamic way to refer to the class itself like there is in a class static method:

```
function Foo1 () {
  this; // <- instance
}

class Foo2 {
  static bar () {
    this; // <- class Foo2
  }

  constructor () {
    this; // <- instance
  }
}
```

I think based on what you posted in the question you understand all of this so far, and want to replicate the concise static function declaration in the second example.

You can do this:

```
function Foo3 () {
   Foo3.bar = function() {
     this; // <- class Foo3
   }
}
```

which seems to do what you want except the `bar` static method will be redefined *every time you call `new Foo3`*. Plus, you still have to refer to the class by name, you can't access it dynamically like you can with `this` in a class static method.

Comment: This is what I was expecting. Thank you for the concise answer, apologies about my ambiguities

Comment: @echoAwoo that's okay, your edit fixed it. If this answer works for you, please accept it (green checkmark next to my answer).